# Python Recursive Updating based on Condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using pandas, and have two data frames:

`df1`:

```
    id date status rpbid rpfid
     1  d1   closed null  10
     2  d2   closed null  11
     3  d3   closed null  null
```

and `df2`:

```
     id date status  rpbid rpfid
     10 d10  updated 1     null
     11 d11  updated 2     9
     9  d9   updated 11    null
```

The idea is that I would like to handle 2 cases: 
 1. where the closed record was the first and final record for that instance (`id 3` in `df1`),
 2. where the closed record has one more updated records linked in df2.
`rfbid` and `rpbid` are for `replacedbyid` and `replacementforid`
So the resulting df would be:

```
id date status rpbid rpfid id2 date2 rpbid2 rpfip2
1  d1   closed null  10    10  d10   1      null
2  d2   closed null  11    9   d9    11     null
3  d3   closed null  null  null null  null   null
```

So far, I've tried doing a first left join on `df1` and `df2`, to get the all of the first recursive joins, I then tried using a loop to check whether `rpbid2` was null, if it wasn't I looked back at `df1` for the `rpdid2` value in the id column of `df2`, I would then like to update that second half of the merged data frame to be the next step in the join where applicable.

Here is the original code: I haven't been able to get it not error

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filename)


df_initial = df.loc[df['LetterStatus']=='CLOSED']
dfx = df.loc[df['LetterStatus']=='UPDATED']


df_merged = pd.merge(df_initial,dfx,how='left',left_on='ReferenceNumber',right_on='ReplacedByRefNumber')
df_copy = df_merged
for row in range(len(df_merged)):
    if  len(str(df_merged.iloc[row]['ReplacedByRefNumber_y'])) > 1:
        row_slice = dfx.iloc[['ReferenceNumber']==df_merged[row['ReplacedByRefNumber_y']]
        if row_slice.size == 0:
            df_merged.iloc[row]['ReplacedByRefNumber_y']='Unknown'
            df_copy.iloc[row]['ReplacedByRefNumber_y']='Unknown'
        else:
            df_copy.iloc[row][24:0]=row_slice


print(df_copy)
```

For more context; if the replacedbyID is null and the status is 'updated', that means the it was first record for that given order.

Comment: Can you please post the code you used and show what it returns? That way we can see how it differs from your expectations

Comment: Also if you don't put into context the data you are trying to manipulate instead of using "encrypted" variable/field names, you'll have to put your data into a minimal example that recreates your problem with an analogous situation because I find very hard to understand the tranformations undercome in order to obtain the desired df

Comment: So, to put it clear: what does data (and the fields) represent? How are the two data frames linked? etc.

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde added the code as I have it now, as well as more context / details

Comment: I'd try to go with a `Graph Theory` solution ... Seems like you have a sequence of directed nodes, and you want to hold the information of the first and last nodes only. The directed edge from `x` to `y` (`x -> y`) can mean `x` replaces `y`, such that you'd just get first and last node info at the end

Comment: @RafaelC That's what I was thinking, the two columns give you both direction ways, but how would you implement something that can traverse those directions, and update itself to only store the first start and end where you have cases such as x1 -> x2 -> x3 and other cases such as just x1 or x1->x2, I know I've reached the end when there's no longer a 'replacement for' value as that tells you the step you just took was the original, but thinking more programmatic approach?

Answer (score -1):

**Disclaimer**: instead of trying to find out to the bottom of question a way to obtain that data frame you want, my intention with this answer is rather to make sure you are absolutely certain of what you are doing, and maybe help you out structure your data a bit better.

For what I see, you have two data frames that have reciprocal bindings in each of them to update their content; problem is you are showing an example in which a row that is to update another element in the other data frame, is as well to be updated.

You are making a mess of the data structure and row identification. I am not very clear about whether the id references in each data frame refer to a row in their own data frame or in the other; ID's are not sorted by inclusion order. When you make your joint data frame, you have recursively included a column to still replace data again, making your data frame grow horizontally with no actual purpose.

I think that you have tried to make your own way of updating data and now you come across problems that you would not otherwise had if you used a data structure that is more common and already thought through to be scalable and easy to manipulate.

1. If you want to update data, best way is to use a data model that has a table inside a database correctly formatted (you can still use pandas; data frames can be your tables). You can update data when an update request comes right **to the place where the to-be-updated content is**, instead of keeping a separate record of updates, that at the same time have update requests themselves. That is very messy. If you want to keep a record of updates, you have to have a table that is constantly being updated, and then another table that shows record of each **already-executed** manipulation into the table. You can store in the latter the previous value and the value it was updated for.
2. You have to name your data frames properly, and when you make a reference to an ID in another data frame, that field's name has to inherently indicate that the reference is to that data frame.
3. You can include dates in the field, you don't have to make references to another table. That does not look good. Just use the `datetime.datetime` module and dump the object into the data frame; Python takes care of the rest.
4. Variable names too should be somewhat self-explanatory: instead of using `rpbid`, and having to explain to everyone that means replacedbyid, just use `replaced_by_id` (note the underscores to separate words).

Comment: J.C - I didn't create this datebase, nor did I design it, I'm trying to work with what I've been given and been asked to look into for solutions in order to answer some business questions, my goal was to limit the table to the width of one join, and update the join in place with further finds rather than continually expanding, as I don't care about the middle steps, only the first and last.